# How do I extract internal nested tag that has the same name as the external tag?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

I am new to data science and was hoping to get your input into this query. When I parse and try and use findall() for "Title", I am getting all the values of Title. What I really want is the value of 'Title' tags within RelatedTerms.

Can anyone help?
Thanks,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Terms>
    <Term>
        <Title>.177 (4.5mm) Airgun</Title>
        <Description>The standard airgun calibre for international target shooting.
        </Description>
        <RelatedTerms>
            <Term>
                <Title>Shooting sport equipment</Title>
                <Relationship>Narrower Term</Relationship>
            </Term>
        </RelatedTerms>
    </Term>
</Terms>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use beautifulsoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
temp  ="""<Terms>
            <Term>
            <Title>.177 (4.5mm) Airgun</Title>
            <Description>The standard airgun calibre for international target shooting. 
            </Description>
            <RelatedTerms>
            <Term>
            <Title>Shooting sport equipment</Title>
            <Relationship>Narrower Term</Relationship>
            </Term>
            </RelatedTerms>
            </Term>"""

temp=BeautifulSoup(temp,"lxml")
#see caps is off
s = temp.find('relatedterms')
print(s.find_all('title'))
```

Output:

```
[<title>Shooting sport equipment</title>]
[Finished in 1.2s]
```

Comment: For parsing HTML and XML, BeautifulSoup is a good library in python

Comment: Thanks Pritish, very helpful. Essentially I am trying to extract for multiple values for each title tag within RelatedTerms. I have been using this BeautifulSoup code but this gives me value for all Title tags not just RelatedTerms one.

"Title = [feature.string for feature in btree.find_all("Title")]
Title"

Anyway to modify this to only get all the Title values within RelatedTerms? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using **xml.etree.ElementTree**:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("file.xml")  # Replace "file.xml" with the name of your XML file
root = tree.getroot()

for related_terms in root.findall("./Term/RelatedTerms"):
    for title_internal in related_terms.findall("./Term/Title"):
        print(title_internal.text)
```

Output:

```
Shooting sport equipment
```

Replace *file.xml* in `tree = ET.parse("test.xml")` with the name of your XML file.